# UseEffect: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I was trying to get the list of call logs in android using `react-native`, I wanted to set up a `button` in which when user clicks permission dialog should've appeared, but instead an error appears as I tried to use `useEffect` hook as the `event` fires and [hook rules](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html) mentions that

> Do not call in event handlers

Tried other possibilities but still not able to reach some solutions.

Here is the code snippet I am using:

```
const ReadLog = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [listData, setListDate] = useState([])

  const ReadFromCalLogs = () => {
    

    useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchData() {
        if (Platform.OS != "ios") {
          try {
            //Ask for runtime permission
            const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
              PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CALL_LOG,
              {
                title: "Call Log Example",
                message: "Access your call logs",
                buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
                buttonNegative: "Cancel",
                buttonPositive: "OK",
              }
            )
            if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
              CallLogs.loadAll().then((c) => setListDate(c))
              CallLogs.load(3).then((c) => console.log(c))
            } else {
              Alert.alert("Call Log permission denied")
            }
          } catch (e) {
            Alert.alert(e.message)
          }
        } else {
          alert(
            "Sorry! You can’t get call logs in iOS devices because of the security concern"
          )
        }
      }
      fetchData()
    }, [])
  }

  return (
    <View>
    <View style={styles.ReadFromCallLogs}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => ReadFromCalLogs()}>
        <Text style={{ color: "#009387", marginTop: 15 }}>
          <MaterialCommunityIcons
            size={Dimensions.iconSize}
            name="phone-log-outline"
              >
              </MaterialCommunityIcons>
          Read from Call Logs?
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    < /View>
            </View>
  )
}

export default ReadLog
```

**what is the elegant way to do this?**

Comment: You don't need to use the useEffect since the function `ReadFromCalLogs` is triggered when the user clicks a button

Answer (score 2):

You can't call a hook inside a function. Hooks can be called only at the top level of the component.

In your code snippet you are calling `useEffect()` hook inside a normal function `ReadFromCalLogs` this is what causing the error. However, you don't need to call `useEffect()` try (Untested):

```js
const ReadFromCalLogs = () => {
  async function fetchData() {
    if (Platform.OS != "ios") {
      try {
        //Ask for runtime permission
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CALL_LOG,
          {
            title: "Call Log Example",
            message: "Access your call logs",
            buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
            buttonNegative: "Cancel",
            buttonPositive: "OK",
          }
        );
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          CallLogs.loadAll().then((c) => setListDate(c));
          CallLogs.load(3).then((c) => console.log(c));
        } else {
          Alert.alert("Call Log permission denied");
        }
      } catch (e) {
        Alert.alert(e.message);
      }
    } else {
      alert(
        "Sorry! You can’t get call logs in iOS devices because of the security concern"
      );
    }
  }
  fetchData().catch((e) => {
    console.warn(e);
  });
};
```

Comment: Then I am getting the error `Possible unhandled promise Rejection`

Comment: @hanan Updated answer. Please try the new solution

Comment: the issue solved. but the permission dialog is not showing.

Comment: Because your code throwing an error. See it in the console and solve it. This is a separate issue

Comment: No error I am seeing here. when clicked it is not showing the permission dialog. I am using Expo if that helps?

Comment: Actually, **Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection** error that you wrote above means that your `fetchData()` failing. I have logged the error to the console `console.warn(e)` so it must appear there.

Comment: well, I have used the updated version, and it is not printing on the `console` from `console.warn(e)`

Comment: Hi @hanan, Currently I can't be in a discussion. As I told you this is a wholly separate issue from this question. Please try to find the new error and then you can open a new question and we can continue to help.